ARM CCA Realm, FVP. Unable to communicate between non secure world and realm guest virtual machine
I have created 4 worlds in Arm fvp realm, secure, non-secure, and root. In non-secure, Linux is running as host. I have created one realm guest VM (virtual machine). Here I can communicate from realm guest VM to host but not from host to realm guest VM. I want to communicate or ping the IP from the host to the guest VM. Is there any suggestion?
I tried creating 4 worlds in Arm fvp realm, secure, non-secure and root. One guest realm VM is created, expecting to communicate from non-secure to guest realm VM and vice-versa.

Welcome to SO. The question is a little vague  and SO is more for programming specific questions. Do you have some code you're having difficulty with? Also, please clarify how the question relates to MongoDB Realm per the Realm tag. Take a moment and review How to ask a question and How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
